# Conditions under which an $A$-submodule is also a $B$-submodule, when $A \subseteq B$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm sorry but I have a silly doubt. Let $U$ be a commutative ring and $M \subseteq U$ a finitely generated $A$-submodule of $U$. Assume moreover that $A \subseteq B \subseteq U$ (where $A$ and $B$ are subrings of $U$). In general, we cannot say whether $M$ is a $B$-submodule. However, when it is verified, then we can prove that $M$ is a finitely generated $B$-submodule of $U$. Now, my question is, in which conditions may I infer that $M$ is a $B$-submodule?

Comment: When you write $A \subseteq B \subseteq U$, do you also mean that $A$ is a subring of $B$ and $B$ a subring of $U$?

Comment: Also, you write "$M$ is a finitely generated $B$-submodule of $U$". How does that make sense? You didn't even have $M$ to be a subset of $U$ to begin with, right?

Comment: I edited my question, in order to fix the details you're underlining

Comment: The obvious and trivial condition is that $BM\subset M$.  What type of condition are you looking for?

Comment: @Mohan: How does $BM$ make sense here?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani    Both are contained in the ring $U$ and multiplication in $U$ makes sense.

Comment: @Mohan: Oh right yes, forgot that part.